# How to GROUP BY a SUBSTRING() in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

I'm trying to write a query to pull some info from our database and I need to group it by part of a string.  So I did GROUP BY substring().  However it appears that even though the column I am substring()ing is in the SELECT statement, it still fails.  I also tried to put the substr() in the select on it's own and do an "AS x" with it, but that also fails as it is executed after the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
M.Cabot_source, 
CASE substring(M.Cabot_source,6,1) 
WHEN 'C' THEN 'CoregUserNameLC' 
WHEN 'P' THEN 'PPC' 
WHEN 'O' THEN 'Organic' 
WHEN 'S' THEN 'Ad Swap' 
WHEN 'I' THEN 'Internal' 
ELSE 'Unknown' 
END as source_type
FROM members_ M 
WHERE M.Cabot_source != '' 
GROUP BY substring(M.Cabot_source,6,1)
```

This is the error it returns to me:

SQL error reported from db Connection:

```
> (0x3ddbe8) Lyris function: SQLClass::SendToSQLInternal()  Lyris error
> description: Command.Open() failed with error code 80040e14  Database
> error information: Error 8120: Column 'members_.Cabot_source' is
> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
> aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  (source: Microsoft OLE DB
> Provider for SQL Server)  SQL Statement: SELECT M.Cabot_source, CASE
> substring(M.Cabot_source,6,1) WHEN 'C' THEN 'CoregUserNameLC' WHEN 'P'
> THEN 'PPC' WHEN 'O' THEN 'Organic' WHEN 'S' THEN 'Ad Swap' WHEN 'I'
> THEN 'Internal' ELSE 'Unknown' END as source_type FROM members_ M
> WHERE M.Cabot_source != '' GROUP BY substring(M.Cabot_source,6,1)
```

Comment: use group by source_type

Comment: I think that the problem is in your `Where`, in the `Select count(*)`. There you are using `Cabot_source`, but it's not in the `Group by` clause, but `substring(M.Cabot_source, 6, 1)` it is..

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:MySQL]?  It looks like you're using [tag:sql-server]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to group over the complete case statement.

```
SELECT 
M.Cabot_source, 
  CASE substring(M.Cabot_source,6,1) 
   WHEN 'C' THEN 'CoregUserNameLC' 
   WHEN 'P' THEN 'PPC' 
   WHEN 'O' THEN 'Organic' 
   WHEN 'S' THEN 'Ad Swap' 
   WHEN 'I' THEN 'Internal' 
   ELSE 'Unknown' 
  END as source_type
FROM members_ M 
WHERE M.Cabot_source != '' 
GROUP BY 
  M.Cabot_source, 
  CASE substring(M.Cabot_source,6,1) 
   WHEN 'C' THEN 'CoregUserNameLC' 
   WHEN 'P' THEN 'PPC' 
   WHEN 'O' THEN 'Organic' 
   WHEN 'S' THEN 'Ad Swap' 
   WHEN 'I' THEN 'Internal' 
   ELSE 'Unknown' 
  END
```

Comment: Oh man I thought you had something there for a sec, but that didn't work either :(

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the field `Cabot_Source` to the group by statement.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I needed, but damn touche man, you're a genius.  I actually ended up just doing the rest with PHP.

Comment: Groupby an alias seems like such a simple feature, it's hard to believe most db engines don't support this... I know groupby comes before select in the execution order but they could at least let us define the alias in the groupby, so that it can be used in the select rather than duplicating the code.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit for the error is :

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members_ M3 WHERE M3.Cabot_source = M.Cabot_source) as names, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members_ M2 WHERE M2.MemberType_ = 'normal' AND M2.Cabot_source = M.Cabot_source)
```

Comment: Yeah that's not it.  I actually removed that before and it was still not working.  I've edited it out so it does not confuse people and put the newer error.

Comment: @PolishHurricane the problems still is the same. You are using `M.Cabot_source` as  first column return, but you don't have it in you group by, because you are grouping by `Substring(M.Cabot_source, 6, 1) `

Answer (score 0):

you can either :

```
select M.Cabot_source + group by M.Cabot_source
```

or use whatever aggregate function, e.g. :

```
 select max(M.Cabot_source)
```

the only exception is MySQL, where there is an implicit aggregate function - i call it `return_random_record(M.Cabot_source)`, but this default (and probably undefined) behaviour of MySQL is not available throught SQL Server drivers

Comment: Yeah this is garbage MS SQL and I'm not dealing with numbers, it's strings.

Comment: it's the same with Oracle and DB2, are they garbage too? and `max()` works with varchars.